# how to join docker composer php laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I know about the laradock, but i need to pass all the steps for myself.

i gonna learn Laravel and the same time recently i have opened for myself docker :)

now i need to join alltogether:
  docker-compose with images:
    - php:7.2.2-apache
    - mariadb
    - phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    - and some how composer

laravel will be on my host outside containers.

so far i have made my own image **"web_server"** from the **php:7.2.2-apache** image and run inside mod_rewrite

```
FROM php:7.2.2-apache

RUN apt update && apt install mc -y && apt install composer -y  
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

my `docker-compose.yml` looks like

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secretpswd"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "test_db"
      MYSQL_USER: "my_user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "secretpswd"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    image: web_server
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    depends_on:
      - web
      - db
    environment:
     PMA_HOST: "db"
     PMA_PORT: 3306
     PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    volumes:
     - ./sessions:/sessions
```

now i have to install composer ...
i have two choices

1. use `composer/composer` image from the docker hub    in this case i
   have no idea how it will be used by laravel and     with laravel
   because laravel will be under the control of separate `web`
   container
2. install composer inside the `web_server` image which is made from
   the `php:7.2.2-apache` image

i have tried but start receiving errors

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   composer : Depends:
>   php-symfony-console (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-symfony-filesystem (>= 2.5) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-symfony-finder (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-symfony-process (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-cli
>               Depends: php-common but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-json-schema but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-ca-bundle (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-ca-bundle (< 2~~) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-semver (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-semver (< 2~~) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-spdx-licenses (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-composer-spdx-licenses (< 2~~) but it is not installable
>               Depends: jsonlint (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
>               Depends: jsonlint (< 2~~) but it is not going to be installed
>               Depends: php-cli-prompt (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-cli-prompt (< 2~~) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-psr-log (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
>               Depends: php-psr-log (< 2~~) but it is not installable
>               Recommends: git but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. The command
>   '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install mc -y && apt install composer
>   -y' returned a non-zero code: 100

so it's time to ask for help.

1. which way should i use?
2. in case of separate `composer/composer` container how to use it
       inside web_server container and how laravel will use it
3. in case of the composer installation inside `php:7.2.2-apache` image
       how to solve those errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best option is to make a separate docker container for composer. so that you don't have composer mixed with your php apache container.

you can add the following lines to your docker-compose file:

```
composer:
    restart: 'no'
    container_name:composer
    image: composer:latest
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    command: composer install -d /var/www/html
    volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www/html/
```

the volume is being synced in the composer container and in your php container so the vendor folder will also be synced between the two containers.

the `restart: no` option is there so that when you run `docker-compose up` the composer container is only being started once, when it is done it is being stopped.

To run composer install you can use: `docker-compose run composer composer install`

You can also use the command on the next line, so that composer install is a little bit faster.

(more information about the package: https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo)

```
command: >
      bash -c "composer global require hirak/prestissimo && composer install -d /var/www/html"
```

Comment: ty for the answer. i have 2 questions:  1) prestissimo need to be executed to create my own image from the `composer/composer` image ?  2) in case of the separate composer container through which container should i run laravel command line tools through the `composer` based container or through the `web_server` container ?   
for example `docker-compose exec CONTAINER_NAME php artisan key:generate`

Comment: 1). prestissimo does not need to execute from your own image, it can be as long as composer is installed on the container your running it.
2). all laravel commands (key:generate) can still run from the `web_server` container.

Comment: thanks for your answers. i dont have `composer` container started. happen smth out of my understanding :) so i have changed `docker-compose.yml`, when i run it for the first time `Creating composer ... done`, after that i dont have `composer` container started. then i run second time `docker-compose` and receive `Starting composer ... done` but still no container with composer started ... smth is wrong or i just do not know how to use that container ?

Comment: ok i reread `composer/composer` description on docker hub and have created separate sh script which uses composer image ... but this is kind of partially ruine the concept of containers, right ? to keep host machine without any installations, with the same success i could install composer nativelly to the host ...

Comment: `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: maybe if you try `docker-compose up` without the `-d` flag you will see more information